# How to set MemorySize for AWS EC2 Instance on Cloudformation Template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

From AWS Cloudformation documentation, I have been only seeing one for a Lambda function, but I am not seeing any for EC2 instances. How to set up your template to make your instance have a specific RAM Size rather than the 512MB which is by default.

Comment: You choose the correct `InstanceType`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html .

Comment: @luk2302 thanks that helped and I went on to check with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65233277/11914520) Martin provided for the size in need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set it up. Amount of RAM and vCPU is tide to instance type. For example you can check here https://www.ec2instances.info/ which instance type would have enough RAM and vCPUs for your needs.